# Bash: How to detect multimedia keypresses in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I've been working on a old kobo ereader(No touch screen) and I've been trying to figure out how to detect when the buttons on it are pressed.

So far I've used hexdump to figure out the keycodes, but they don't work like a regular keyboard in that showkey doesn't work on them. Here's the hexdump output I got for the buttons:

```
hexdump  /dev/input/event0
upPress 0000000 fc92 5512 92dd 0003 0001 0067 0001 0000
upRelease 0000010 fc92 5512 7905 0006 0001 0067 0000 0000
rightPress 0000020 fcab 5512 0cec 000b 0001 006a 0001 0000
rightRelease 0000030 fcab 5512 7de5 000d 0001 006a 0000 0000
downPress 0000040 fcb6 5512 48eb 0001 0001 006c 0001 0000
downRelease 0000050 fcb6 5512 b9e4 0003 0001 006c 0000 0000
leftPress 0000060 fcc0 5512 2b98 000f 0001 0069 0001 0000
leftRelease 0000070 fcc1 5512 3342 0002 0001 0069 0000 0000
middlePress 0000080 fccd 5512 acaa 0000 0001 001c 0001 0000
middleRelease 0000090 fccd 5512 1da4 0003 0001 001c 0000 0000
```

I've determined from this that the keycodes are the 7th number, so 0x67 for example. The only problem I have now is I can't figure out how to detect those in a shell script.

This has got me stumped, right now the device has Linux 2.6.28, Busybox v1.17.1 and a few other programs. It is connected to the internet though, so I might be able to install some stuff, but there's no package manager so I'd prefer not to.

Edit: Stuff I've tried -
Read doesn't work, atleast the way I'm using it.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -n 1 -s key
echo "key pressed:" $key
```

Lots of  Google searches - most of them require X, which I don't have. The bind command might work, but I don't have it on the system.

Edit 2: More things -

More research has pointed me to the cat command, it shows the output from the keys in a weird code like this:

```
cat /dev/input/event0
T)U┐Ä☺g☺T)Utè☺gW)U╗☺l☺W)Uúp
☺lY)U3⌐
       ☺l☺Y)U"☺lZ)Uë"
☺l☺Z)Uæ║
        ☺l\)U║╙☺i☺\)U▓D♥☺i
```

Unfortunately it looks like it's different every time, so I don't know how to make sense of it.

Comment: look here for questions about read 1 keypress at a time for bash/ksh. Then use a case statement to process the character that you retrieve. Except for  people that have a kobo ereader, this would be difficult to do any debugging on. (IHMO). Good luck!

Comment: Ah yes, I've already tried using read, the problem is it won't pick up the button presses.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `read` is buffered. Shell programming is notably unsuited for binary real-time programming. You should really consider writing a small C utility.

Comment: I believe there is a way to unbuffer `read`, but I don't have time to dig it up. Also, if you've already tried techniques X, Y, and Z, then that should be mentioned in your question. Others may be able to help debug a specific technique, as is, we're left to guess. Good luck.

Comment: Think I may be onto something. If it actually works then wow I'm stupid. The cat command appears to respond to the keys. It's a weird format, but who knows, I might be able to do something with the output.